# did not get public profile information and email by Facebook java script sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to make web application and login with Facebook using its java script SDK but i am stuck on this problem
API call:

```js
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

This API call just give two inforamtion
{"name":"Name","id":"74.......91"}

How to get full public profile information plus email address

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email,...'}, function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

It is called "Declarative Fields", you need to specify the fields you want to get.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Of course you need to ask for the `email` permission in the authorization process too.

Comment: Thanks it really works now